# How do I stop DeprecationWarning for Python 2.6?

Tags: centos, python, cron, yum, certbot

I have to run this command daily in a cron to refresh certifications.

```
# /root/certbot-auto renew --quiet
/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cryptography/__init__.py:26: DeprecationWarning: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of cryptography will drop support for Python 2.6
  DeprecationWarning
```

It's always mailing me the error. How do I upgrade my python to avoid this error? I already ran `yum update` but everything is up to date.

```
Installed Packages
Name        : python
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.6.6
```

Reference: Certbot: https://certbot.eff.org/#centos6-apache

CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing `scl` and using this in the crontab

```
@daily scl enable python27 "/root/certbot-auto renew --quiet"
```

```
[root@server ~]# python --version
Python 2.6.6
[root@server ~]# python2 --version
Python 2.6.6
[root@server ~]# scl enable python27 "python --version"
Python 2.7.13
```

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 6.x (all releases of CentOS 6) comes with Python 2.6, which is, as you found out, outdated and not supported anymore.

Luckily you can install Python 2.7 besides 2.6:

```
yum -y install centos-release-SCL
yum -y install python27
```

Then you need to replace the Python version used by Let's Encrypt with the new Python 2.7 like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
cd letsencrypt
sed -i "s|--python python2|--python python2.7|" letsencrypt-auto
./letsencrypt-auto --verbose
```

I did not find this out myself, so all credit goes to *eva2000* of the Let's Encrypt Community.

You may need to replace `letsencrypt-auto` with `cerbot-auto` as the original answer is from 2015.

Sources:

- https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/redhat-centos-6-x-users-need-python-2-7/2190
- https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/wiki/installing-python-2.7-on-centos-6.3.-follow-this-sequence-exactly-for-centos-machine-only
- https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL

Edit: Other sources mention the need to install `centos-release-SCL` in order to install Python 2.7

Comment: This gave an error: `Error getting repository data for ius, repository not found`

Comment: I've found a slightly different solution. See the edit

Comment: OK I see 'software collections' is way to have multiple versions installed at once, like `rvm` for Ruby. Why can't I just upgrade Python to 2.7 and get rid of 2.6?

Comment: @Chloe I don't know, I don't use CentOS, but for some reason the OS has  scripts that require Python 2.6.

Comment: That didn't work: `# sed -i "s|--python python2|--python python2.7|" certbot-auto` and `# ./certbot-auto renew --quiet` yields `/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cryptography/__init__.py:26: DeprecationWarning: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of cryptography will drop support for Python 2.6`

Comment: This isn't a good idea because everytime certbot updates itself (like every 2 weeks) then it will overwrite the script.

Comment: Unfortunately, package python27 is empty! `yum info python27`; `Size        : 0.0`